# Access script from other script Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote a small asset (editor) for Unity. It works well. All the code, however, was in a single Monobehaviour and I wanted to divide it into three additional scripts, each of them for a certain type of activity (read / write files, object management, navigation management).I thus collided with the methods requested by Unity to access data in other scripts (I come from Delphi with its easy units).
The solution I found is this: the various components in the inspector use SendMessage to call the methods in the Target script and some of these methods call other methods in the three additional scripts. The three scripts do not access each other but must share Target script variables. To do this in the Target script:

```
[HideInInspector] public FileScript1 Script1;
[HideInInspector] public FileScript2 Script2;
[HideInInspector] public FileScript3 Script3;

    public void Start () {
    Script1 = FindObjectOfType (typeof(FileScript1)) as FileScript1;
    Script2 = FindObjectOfType (typeof(FileScript2)) as FileScript2;
    Script3 = FindObjectOfType (typeof(FileScript3)) as FileScript3;
}
```

and to access the other scripts I can use Script1.myMethod.

In the three scripts I instantiate

```
public FileTarget myTarget;
```

Finally I have to add the three scripts as components of the Target script and drag the FileTarget object on each one from the Hierarchy. Then I can use [HideInInspector]. This way I can also access the Target script.

All this seemed very laborious and I thought of using Static classes for the three scripts instead of Monobehaviour (these three scripts are not objects in Hierarchy).
But apart from not having to instantiate the three scripts in the Target script, I still need to instantiate the target script in the three scripts and add them as Target components.
I definitely do not want to ask you to teach programming but could you direct me to the best way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Do all of your scripts require to be inherited from MonoBehaviour? Reading and Writing files does not sound like it requires it (the other two may or may not need it, we don't have enough details about them)

Comment: With this asset, I create meshes by drawing them directly in Game View. The main code is in the Target (e.g Awake, Update with Input.GetMouseButtonDown, OnEditorChangedPlayMode and other methods to draw). Then I save the data on disk. To do this I call methods from the additional script that must read the data from the Target script. More or less the other two scripts behave in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your three scripts do not need to be attached to Gameobjects you can simply define them as normal C# classes and instantiate them from `Target`.
Additionally you can give them a reference to `Target` as a parameter in the constructor that you can save as a private member to access later, e.g.:

```
class FileScript1
{
   private Target _target;
   public FileScript1(Target target)
   {
      _target = target;
   }
}
```

And create the objects in `Start` of `Target` like this:

```
private FileScript1 Script1;

public void Start () {
    Script1 = new FileScript1(this);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, this way the scripts communicate with the Target script without the need to add them as components. I have marked your answer as solved. Unfortunately, my up-vote is not accepted because I just signed up. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're going to have these scripts attached to GameObjects, you'll want to use [GetComponent<>()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html). The way the call works is that it will return a component of the specified type, or null if it doesn't exist. This way you can attach your script (which is also a component) to the GameObject of your choice, then make the call.

For example:

```
myClassVariable = this.gameObject.getComponent<myClass>();
```

Comment: What I was wondering is whether it is really necessary to add the three scripts as components or if there were other ways to share variables and methods.